# NullpointerException. Do not want to add empty lines to List from file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

While adding the lines of a text file to List , i donot want to add empty lines to the List. I tried this but not working :

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File(text.txt));
List <String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
while(s.hasNext()){
if (s.nextLine()!=null){
names.add(s.nextLine());
}}
```

My text file looks like this:

```
name1   erer    | 26-08-1988

name2 rerer   | 13-07-1988       

name3  erer    | 14-07-1988   

name4  weww |   13-07-2001   
name5 ewew | 18-10-1987
```

Comment: Its giving error like NosuchElement Exception if the first line is also empty but if not, storing only few names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You skip a line each time (double call to `nextLine()` in each iteration), should be:

```
String line;
if ((line=s.nextLine())!=null && !line.trim().equals("")){
    names.add(line);
}
```

or even:

```
if (!"".equals(line=s.nextLine()))
```

Code edited to reflect (correct) comments.

Comment: ... and if the OP doesn't want to add empty lines, then test for empty strings before adding.

Comment: there is no check if line is empty (zero-length string)

Comment: You should use `isEmpty()` instead of `.equals("")`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
List <String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
String line = "";
while(s.hasNext()){
    if ((line = s.nextLine())!=null && !line.isEmpty()){
        names.add(line);
    }
}
```

Checks the scanner has input, and that it is not empty

Answer (score 1):

You call `s.nextLine()` twice, you could do this instead:

```
String line = s.nextLine();
if (line != null) {
   names.add(line);
}
```

Comment: there is no check if line is empty (zero-length string)

Answer (score 0):

1) When you check `s.nextLine() != null` you are consuming a line, better store it in a variable first
2) Check that the variable is not empty (for example, length==0, or all spaces, tabs, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
String line;
if (((line = s.nextLine()) != null) && !"".equals(line.trim()) {
    names.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `s.nextLine()` twice?

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE is caused by 2 calls to nextLine() each iteration, but only the first call is checked if hasNext().

The solution would be:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
List <String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
while(s.hasNext()){
    if ((line = s.nextLine())!=null && !line.trim().isEmpty()){
    // .trim() removes whire spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string
        names.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: by this , storing alternative lines, bot continuosly.